# printing variable number lines to output

Tags: bash

I would like to have a script to modify some large text files (100k records) such that, for every record, a number of lines in the output is created equivalent to the difference in columns 3 and 2 of every input line. In the output I want to print the record name (column 1), and a step-wise walk between the numbers contained in columns 2 and 3.

Sample trivial input could be (tab separated data, if it makes a difference)

```
a   3   5
b   10  14
```

with the desired output (again, ideally tab separated)

```
a   3   4
a   4   5
b   10  11
b   11  12
b   12  13
b   13  14
```

It's a challenge sadly beyond my (very) limited abilities.

Can anyone provide a solution to the problem, or point me in the right direction? In an ideal world I would be able to be integrate this into a bash script, but I'll take anything that works!

Comment: It would be pretty trivial to do this in Python.  If you need to integrate it with some other bash script you could have that script run the Python program which saves the output to a temp file that the rest of the bash script uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' '
    $2 >= $3 {print; next}
    {for (i=$2; i<$3; i++) print $1, i, i+1}
' filename
```

Comment: will skip lines where `$2` and `$3` are same.

Comment: @Jaypal: in fact, as with yours, this solution does report lines where $2 = $3.

Comment: @RobS, that's because I edited my answer based on Jaypal's comment

Answer (score 3):

Bash solution:

```
while read h f t ; do
    for ((i=f; i<t; i++)) ; do
        printf "%s\t%d\t%d\n" $h $i $((i+1))
    done
done < input.txt
```

Perl solution:

```
perl -lape '$_ = join "\n", map join("\t", $F[0], $_, $_ + 1), $F[1] .. $F[2] - 1' input.txt
```

Comment: `echo $'\t'` is awful when the fully POSIXLY portable `printf "$h\t$i\t\$((i+1))\n"` does it.

Comment: @Jens: True. Updated (and removed the \ before the `$`).

Comment: @Jens, If you're going to use printf, use format specifiers: `printf "%s\t%d\t%d\n" "$h" $i $((i+1))` -- if $h happens to contain "a%sb" then the output ("ab") will be different from the input.

Comment: @glennjackman Good point in general (I used no %s because of the assumption of single letters as the first column; but assumption is the mother of all screw-ups, we know :-)

Comment: Thanks; I didn't use the bash solution in the end because it doesn't report records where $2=$3.
@Jens: in fact, my first column is not just single letters, so the % was a useful addition.

Comment: @RobS: That was not part of the specification. To get better response, try to be more precise next time.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk '$3!=$2 { while (($3 - $2) > 1) { print $1,$2,$2+1 ; $2++} }1' inputfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Fully POSIX, and no unneeded loop variables:

```
$ while read h f t; do
    while test $f -lt $t; do
        printf "%s\t%d\t%d\n" "$h" $f $((++f))
    done
done < input.txt
a       3       4
a       4       5
b       10      11
b       11      12
b       12      13
b       13      14
```